# Page elements don't visibly update during load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm probably missing something really obvious here...

I'm showing a dialog box with progress bar during page load. The dialog and progress bar are both jQueryUI widgets. There are a couple of phases of loading - the page makes a load of jQuery $.get() requests to load resources, then on the $(document).ajaxStop() event, does things with those resources. I'm updating the progress bar and some status text throughout this process.

The issue is that as soon as the ajaxStop event fires, updates stop. The code works nicely during resource loading, but then freezes and I don't see any of the updates during processing. If I put a breakpoint on a post-ajaxStop update in Chrome and step through the code, the screen updates correctly so I know that the code works.

Can anyone explain why everything updates nicely during my AJAX loading phase, but then stops on the ajaxStop event? Is there an easy way to make updates continue afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you possibly post a link so that it can be reproduced please?

Comment: I can't post a link unfortunately. Further research suggests that this is because browsers don't ever update the screen while Javascript is actually executing. I guess it works during the Ajax phase as control is being returned to the browser while the requests complete. I need some way to return control to the browser on each iteration - this may be possible using setTimeout or similar, but it's difficult in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Several hours of searching later, the [following blog](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2009/07/03/not-blocking-the-ui-in-tight-javascript-loops) pointed me in the right direction:

There's a jQuery extension described in the entry which allows you to define two functions, one to compute and one to update the UI. It schedules them alternately using the setTimeout function.

I've had to rewrite my code in something akin to continuation passing style so that each function schedules its continuation to run using setTimeout. This returns control to the browser for long enough for the screen to be updated.

This feels like a bit of a hack though to get round browser/Javascript limitations. Anyone know of a better way?